# How do you sterilize a non-metal canning funnel?

Tags: cleaning, canning

Non-metal canning funnels exist, but how can you use them safely? (For example, Ball makes one)

Specifically, is it possible to sterilize them safely, without damaging the product?

Comment: Do you mean sterilize (as in a hospital) or sanitize (as in a restaurant) ?  What do you want to do with the product?

Comment: At the very least, you could use them in canning processes where it's not necessary to presterilize the jars (e.g., pressure canning, or processes involving boiling the sealed cans for a sufficient amount of time.)

Comment: Would an answer based on how homebrewers sanitize plastic equipment for brewing be helpful?

Comment: The purpose is to sanitize tools for canning jam via non-pressurized boiling method (i.e. rise the temp of the jars to 212F). From what I've read, all jars and tools (basically anything that could reside in the jars) should be sterilized. 

@ThePhoton I'd be interested as I ended up just sanitizing and hoping (cuz I didn't want to risk boiling my flimsy plastic canning funnel), but I'm not sure if it'd answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can sterilize using a chemical agent that is used to sterilize baby bottles.

https://www.milton-tm.com/en

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of plastics that can handle high heat, and I've never seen anything sold as a "canning funnel" that couldn't be put into boiling water for sterilization.

I would assume that the packaging would contain sterilization instructions, but you can also see if the company has that info on their website.

(I tried looking for info on Ball funnels, but Ball actually licenses its logo to Rubbermaid for home canning jars, and [I didn't see funnels on that site](https://www.freshpreserving.com/products).  I don't know if they license the logo to another company for other canning-related home products.)

Comment: "I would assume that the packaging would contain sterilization instructions" I thought the same thing, but it had no instructions or information regarding maximum temperature, etc. I also tried looking for information on the Ball funnel, but could only find other websites listing the same product. 

regarding plenty of plastics handling high heat, I was leery of testing that out.

Comment: I guess it's possible it could be a cheaply made counterfeit, and wouldn't actually handle heat  (I'm pretty sure I've gotten knock-off Norpro items before through Amazon).  You might want to try contacting the people from the website w/ the bell canning jars, and ask them : https://www.freshpreserving.com/contact-us

Comment: Good idea. I've sent a contact request to Ball for the funnel that comes with the kit (upc 014400108082). I will update the question/answer if I hear back